# Hazelcast SQL queries in dynamic ways

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm working on Hazelcast SQL queries.

I have a question.

To fetch hazelcast value by key I'm using

```
Predicate idPredicate = eo.key().get("id").equal("abc@gmail.com").and(eo.key().get("name").equal("alin"));
```

how to make this dynamic i mean how to handle this methods when we get input from the user

For example:-

id='abc@gmail.com' and name='alin'

or

id IN ('','') AND name IN ('','')

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SqlPredicate](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/query/impl/predicates/SqlPredicate.java). Here are some examples:

- [SqlQueryMember](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/distributed-map/sqlquery/src/main/java/SqlQueryMember.java)
- [SqlPredicateTest](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/test/java/com/hazelcast/query/impl/predicates/SqlPredicateTest.java)